# PySerial - cannot send STX

Tags: python, pyserial

Ok, so I am a complete noob to pySerial.  I am trying to communicate to a piece of lab equipment, but am having trouble just sending the STX (Start of Text) command.  So far, my basic code looks like:

```
ser = serial.Serial(0, 19200, timeout=1,parity=serial.PARITY_ODD, rtscts=0)
ser.write(0x02) #ASCII STX is 0x2 in hex
```

But when I look at the 232 data on my scope, the STX I'm trying to send, doesn't look anything like a STX command sent in Hperterminal.

Any ideas?  I am sure this is incredibly straight forward and I am just overlooking something trivial.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The write function in serial class accepts bytes or strings. You are passing an integer so the result is unknown, maybe is casting it to str so you are sending the char '2'.

The correct way to do it is :

```
ser = serial.Serial(0, 19200, timeout=1,parity=serial.PARITY_ODD, rtscts=0)
ser.write(chr(0x02)) #ASCII STX is 0x2 in hex
```

Comment: Ahh, yes, that did the trick!  Thanks!  I had tried sending a byte, but not passing it as a chr yet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the same configuration is used for HyperTerminal and PySerial. You should make sure that the following are same:

- Baudrate (you are using 19200)
- Parity  (you are using PARITY_ODD)
- Number of data bits (pySerial default 8)
- Stop bits (pySerial default 1)

Comment: I did check, and the settings are the same.